# upgrade from ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10 failed, now loads "grub rescue"

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, grubrescue

I attempted to upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10 last night.  Installation seemed to go fine, and this morning I had a message like "restart now to complete installation".  So I restart, get an initial "Loading Operating System ..." message, followed by "error: file not found.  Then it kicks into "grub rescue>" mode.

Previously I have this running as a dual boot (window 7) and I just ran the upgrade to 12.10 via the update manager in ubuntu.  Any ideas on what is going on here, or what the error means?  I know my way around the command line, but this is above my pay grade.  Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Try to use the [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#A2nd_option_:_install_Boot-Repair_in_Ubuntu) tool to fix the problem. It wants only a boot from LiveCD/DVD/USB of Ubuntu and "Try Ubuntu" and then apply 2 commands in terminal. Follow the instructions.

Comment: Awesome, thanks NikTh, need to get my hands on a boot disk and I'll give this a try.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of these answers were helpful, in the end I used the boot-repair tool to fix my issues.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might just have a **UUID problem**. So it might be a good idea to try this by booting from USB including live **Ubuntu, Parted Magic, Rescatux**, etc. (see, for example, http://liveusb.info/), starting **Gparted** to **check the UUID of your Ubuntu partition** against the value in the file **/etc/fstab** in that Ubuntu partition on your hard disk.
If UUID values are the same, you can then move on to "boot-repair" and then "rescatux" as mentioned.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response Sadi.  I ended up trying what NikTh recommended and it worked great.  I booted into a USB thumbdrive, installed boot-repair and it fixed my grub issue.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I've never had any luck upgrading Ubuntu.  Its always best to do a clean install.  The problem is grub and the mbr (I think, can someone confirm this). A good tip is to have /home on a different partition so you don't lose much if you have to nuke you OS.  Back to your original question one of the best tools for fixing grub is [rescatux](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/rescatux/).  This will almost all grub issues.

**To you rescatux:**

1. Burn to usb of dvd
2. Boot the device
3. Follow the on screen instructions to fix grub
4. Reboot